# AttributeError: MainPage object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, python-unittest

I am using Unittest + Pytest. I need perfrom move over.
Here is first page:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest
import unittest
from page.home.main_page import MainPage
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

class MainPageTests(unittest.TestCase):
def setUp(self):
baseURL = "https://grin.co/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
driver.get(baseURL)
self.mb = MainPage(driver)
self.driver = driver

```
@pytest.mark.run(order=1)

def testtitle(self):
    self.mb.creatormenu()
```

Here is second:

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

import time

class MainPage():
def **init**(self,driver):
self.driver = driver

```
def creatormenu(self):
    time.sleep(2)
    element = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "menu-item-17096")

    actions = ActionChains(self)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    print("Mouse Hovered on element")
```

And I gets error:

```
         device.actions = []
```

> ```
>   self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
> ```

E       AttributeError: 'MainPage' object has no attribute 'execute'

venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py:88: AttributeError
======================================================================================= short test summary info ========================================================================================
FAILED Tests/home/mane_page_test.py::MainPageTests::testtitle - AttributeError: 'MainPage' object has no attribute 'execute'

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: actually...found myself:          actions = ActionChains(self.driver)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your answer Oleg!
I had the same issue when tried to use the following functions without ".driver":

```
def switchToNewWindow(self):
    remote = Remote(self.driver)
    remote.switch_to.window(remote.window_handles[1])
```

and

```
def moveSlideBar(self, Xamount, Yamount, locator):
    move = ActionChains(self.driver)
    move.click_and_hold(locator).move_by_offset(Xamount, Yamount).release().perform()
```